# Finding out the best experimentalist based on statistical analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, friedman-test

There are $m$ students in a laboratory. Each student is assigned the same task, which is described below.

i). $n$ unknown standards are given to each of them.

ii). Each standard has to be analyzed $p$ times each.

iii). There is no interaction among the students; they do not share any information about their results among each other.

Now, from this, how do we find which is the best student among $m$ for carrying out the analysis.

I approached the problem in the following way:

i). For each standard, the sum of squares of errors can be calculated for all $m$.

ii). Thus, for each standard, we would have which is the best student among $m$ based on who is having the lowest sum of squares of errors.

iii). For $n$ standards, we would have $n$ sum of squares of errors for each $m$. So in this case, how do we combine all of them to find out "Which student among $m$ is best in analysis of $n$ standards?"

Can we apply Friedman test for this problem. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: When you mention the Friedman test, do you refer to its test statistic or do you actually want a test? From my point of view "finding the best" is not something that requires a statistical test (only if you wonder whether the best is significantly better than the others; but even if not significant, nobody else is estimated as better).

Comment: What's wrong with picking the student who has the overall smallest sum of squared errors?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in choosing the overall smallest sum of squared errors. I was thinking if this problem could be addressed using Friedman test or Kruskal-Wallis test. Yes. it is quite true that if all students are equally good, then one student may not perform significantly better than others. What I wish to confirm is "Have all students performed equally well within 95% confidence interval?"

Comment: Hypotheses are about populations, not confidence intervals (which are a property of samples). Possibly a better-framed version of that last question could be addressed by an equivalence test.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.